# Find The Minimum Value of the quantity

Tags: calculus

Find the minimum value of the quantity $$\frac{(a^2+3a+1)(b^2+3b+1)(c^2+3c+1)}{abc}$$,where $$a,b,c>0$$ and $$ a,b,c\in R $$are positive real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\frac{(a^2+3a+1)(b^2+3b+1)(c^2+3c+1)}{abc} = \left(3+a+\frac1a \right)\left(3+b+\frac1b \right)\left(3+c+\frac1c \right)$$

Now can you show that $x + \dfrac1x$ has a minimum of $2$ for positive real $x$?

Comment: done....thank you so much.....

Comment: @soumajitdas, if this answer helped you pls consider accepting it as your answer by clicking the green tick mark.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{a^2 + 3a + 1}{a} = a + \dfrac{1}{a} + 3 \geq 2 + 3 = 5$ by AM-GM. So $LHS \geq 5^3 = 125$ with equality at $  a = b = c = 1$